# How to change label colour in error state in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

could you please tell me How to change label colour and input field colour in error state in material ?

I tried like this

```
<FormControl>
                  <TextField
                    required
                    error
                    classes={{
                      error: this.props.classes.error

                    }}
                    InputLabelProps={{
                      shrink: true,
                      FormLabelClasses: {
                        asterisk: this.props.classes.labelAsterisk,
                        error: this.props.classes.error

                      }
                    }}
                    id="standard-name"
                    label="Name"
                    margin="normal"
                    helperText="Some important text"
                  />
                </FormControl>
```

here is the documentation
https://material-ui.com/api/input/
my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/007k3v472w

currently on `error` state it is showing color of `red` label and `red` border of input field .I want `green` label and green `border` in input field
any update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property rules defined in the style object do not override those provided in the default theme because they have less specificity.

For one, the input label error color is given in the CSS selector `'.root.error'` ignoring Component prefixes added in the selector names.

What selectors are used to target an element can be discovered in the Styles section of your Browser's Developer Console.

[image: CSS Property Inspector in Dev Console]

This is the same with the color for the asterisk and form helper text error state.

To generate similar selectors you need to write the styles object as:

```
const styles = {
  root: {
    '&$error': {
      color: "green"
    }
  },
  asterisk: {
    '&$error': {
      color: "green"
    }
  },
  underline: {
    '&$error:after': {
      borderBottomColor: "green",
    }
  },
  error: {
  }
};
```

Here I replaced `color` from `red` to `green`.

[image: Rendered UI change]

In the `TextField` override `InputProps.classes`, `FormHelperTextProps.classes`, and `InputLabelProps.FormLabelClasses`

```
const { classes } = this.props 
//...
return (
  <TextField
    //...
    InputProps={{
      classes: {
        root: classes.root,
        error: classes.error,
        underline: classes.underline
      }
    }}
    FormHelperTextProps={{
      classes: {
        root: classes.root,
        error: classes.error
      }
    }}
    InputLabelProps={{
      shrink: true,
      FormLabelClasses: {
        root: classes.root,
        asterisk: classes.asterisk,
        error: classes.error
      }
    }}
    //...
  />
)
```